# viewing source of namespace resolver functions linux fedora

Tags: linux

I want to see the source of functions like ns_initparse(), res_search() etc. Where can I look for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's are the steps I take find the source for `res_search`.

```
$ man res_search
```

I see in that man page: `Link with -lresolv`

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libresolv*
```

Oops, nothing there. [Where else do we look](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)? How about:

```
$ ls /lib/libresolv*
/lib/libresolv-2.7.so  /lib/libresolv.so.2
```

Great. Now [what package is that from](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/drafts/rpm-guide-en/ch-using-rpm-db.html#id2939092)?

```
$ rpm -qf /lib/libresolv-2.7.so
glibc-2.7-2
```

Ah. It's in [`glibc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). Now, there are two choices. I can fetch the source RPMs, and look through those, in order to get the exact version that that my system was built from, but [that's a bit complicated to set up](http://hacktux.com/fedora/source/rpm).

If you don't need the exact source RPM that you were built from, you can instead look through the [upstream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development)) source code. Just look around the [`glibc` site](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) to find the [source code](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/#Availability), and start looking through there.

```
$ curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.7.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 20.2M  100 20.2M    0     0  12.3M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12.8M
$ tar xzf glibc-2.7.tar.gz
$ cd glibc-2.7
$ find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep res_search
./resolv/res_data.c:res_search(const char *name, /* domain name */
./resolv/res_data.c:# undef res_search
./resolv/res_data.c:weak_alias (__res_search, res_search);
```

And there you have it!

If you have [Git](http://git-scm.com/) installed, instead of just downloading the tarball, you could clone the git repo, and look through that. That way, you can also look at any past or future version, to see how it's changed over time.

```
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
$ cd glibc
$ git checkout glibc-2.7
$ git grep res_search 
resolv/res_data.c:res_search(const char *name,  /* domain name */
resolv/res_data.c:# undef res_search
resolv/res_data.c:weak_alias (__res_search, res_search);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are interested in Fedora specific stuff, but I have had good luck with [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) for finding source code for certain functions.

Comment: Thank u very much. This is a great link. I did not know that we search functions at google code.

Comment: The chances are that those library functions are not Fedora specific.

Comment: Google Code Search is now dead. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778034/replacement-for-google-code-search for various replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Once you figure out which package provides the functions you are interested in, all you need to do on Fedora is `debuginfo-install glibc-2.7-2`. More info [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/StackTraces#What_are_debuginfo_rpms.2C_and_how_do_i_get_them.3F).