# Current alternatives to Google Code

Tags: software-distribution, google-code

If I understand things correctly, at the end of the year Google Code will be shutting down most of what is useful for an open source project I help maintain, described below.

I'm wondering what the current alternatives are to Google Code? I'm looking for a site that has the following attributes, some of which are attractive about Google Code (but which will not be available soon or in the long term):

- free
- svn/mercurial/git version control services that we can use to manage code and share trunk/branches with the public
- hosts files (source code and prebuilt binaries) with reasonable storage (we currently have a 4 GB quota, but we don't use much of it, at this time)
- offers wiki-like or relatively free-form web space to publish documentation (text and graphics)

I guess we could "roll our own" server to do all of this, but then it becomes a maintenance issue for all the services that run in the background. So I'm wondering if there are other companies that offer this kind of setup for open source projects?

(Note: While this is a software development question, it is more about the distribution side of things. If this is the wrong spot for this question, feel free to comment on where I should move it. Thanks for your help, hiveminds.)

Comment: is your code open source? I'm thinking of github or bitbucket

Comment: I think github doesn't host files -- is that correct? I'm looking for a site that meets the criteria above.

Comment: what sort of file do you have in mind? i think there is no restriction on the type of file you can commit. there are some restrictions for the free accounts though

Comment: Source code, prebuilt binaries, textual documentation and images.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, github does not want their site used for hosting anything but source code. So if I went with github, I would have to use a third-party for hosting binaries (and probably images embedded within documentation, and any other static files). I'm looking for a service that offers everything on one site, the way Google Code used to but will no longer at the end of the year. Hopefully this clarifies my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for Google Code Search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778034/replacement-for-google-code-search)

Comment: github would work fine for this if your code is open source -- make a website with pages and put the zip etc there with a download link

Comment: GitHub supports hosting files. Go to 'Releases' tab in your repository and upload them.

Comment: On [softwarerecs.se]: [Google Code downloads discontinued: What to use instead?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9796/60)

Comment: Thanks for that link -- I ended up going with GitHub but it's nice to see that others are asking the same question.

Answer (score 5):

Google code isn't shutting down, it's just stop hosting binaries.

For your binaries you have [Bintray.com](http://bintray.com).

Bintray is a social platform for community-based software distribution. It is also the only platform that integrates developer tools (Build tools, etc.) and APIs, allowing full process automation, including auto-generating of indexes for multiple repository formats and also, the platform is highly available and optimized to deliver high-performance downloads (CDN).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [codeplex](http://codeplex.com) would fit these needs

Comment: Codeplex fits only for projects target .NET platform. Binary distribution has much larger scope.

Comment: that's actually not at all true.  there is nothing stopping you from using codeplex for non-.NET projects.  they even have support for git and mercurial.

Comment: And let's say, Maven, or npm, or bundler will be able to retrieve from it by using their APIs? I am not even sure about NuGet, frankly.

Comment: @JBaruch I'm sure bintray is cool and all but maybe do some research before downvoting

Comment: It's not about Bintray. It's about CodePlex. [While CodePlex encompasses a wide variety of projects, including SQL, WPF and Windows Forms-related projects, major activities center around the .NET framework, including ASP.NET, and Microsoft's collaboration server, SharePoint. The most prominent and used project that was born inside CodePlex, the AJAX Control Toolkit is a joint project between the community and Microsoft.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex) It can't get more MS-oriented than this.

Comment: @JBaruch which of OP's requirements are unmet by CodePlex?  I didn't see "don't be associated with Microsoft" on the list and I'm sure you can find more effective ways to position your company against this pseudo-competitor

Comment: So, you changed the argument, I see. It's good to know that "CodePlex is not MS" is behind us. Now, for the new one - once you weren't asked specifically  for MS project management, proposing a solution that is MS only is wrong. And the argument "but it didn't say 'No MS' won't hold, because you don't expect the question to list all the possible technologies, asking about each one of them, do you? General question deserves general answer, like GitHub or SourceForge, or whatever that works for _everything_, not just MS or Java. And again - CodePlex is not a Bintray competitor, in any way.

Comment: Its not MS-only.  I don't understand how you got that impression.  All the changes they've made over the past few years have been to make it even better outside the MS ecosystem.